# How would you create a "weekly" archive?

Tags: categories, loop, archives, wp-get-archives

I'm looking to create individual archives for each category of my website, but want to them to break into weeks. Check out the linked image (can't embed images as a new user?):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynHWb.png

I'm finding real difficulties here: 
1) Breaking archives out weekly, 
2) Adding the Date at the Top
3) Listing each post as a list item with some HTML in it…

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $args = array(
    'type'            => 'weekly',
    'limit'           => ,
    'format'          => 'html', 
    'before'          => ,
    'after'           => ,
    'show_post_count' => false,
    'echo'            => 1 ); ?>
<?php wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>
```

See this Codex article: [`wp_get_archives`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives)

Comment: check out the linked image. I think @Ben is looking to break up the posts by week, rather than just display links to weekly archives.

Answer (score 0):

I use the filter `widget_archives_dropdown_args` to limit number of months in the default monthly archive widget - you can modify it to change the `type` to `weekly`.

```
function my_limit_archives( $args ) {    
    $args[ 'type' ] = 'weekly'; 
    return $args;
}
add_filter(
    'widget_archives_dropdown_args',
    'my_limit_archives'
);
```