# weekly archive for custom category

Tags: categories, archives

```
<?php $args = array(
    'cat'             => '2',
); ?>

<?php wp_get_archives($args);  ?>
```

I pull out the custom category with the above codes, it works fine & shows up "February 2013". 
here, My question is can I display it in "weekly".

I put `(type = weekly)` in `$args`, but it displays weekly posts archive, not the category.

My question is almost same as [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17419/how-would-you-create-a-weekly-archive). It seems the questioner didn't get a clear answer yet.
I'm also looking for the answer..

Comment: There isn't any cat parameter for wp_get_archives function. How r u using it?

Comment: I'm using small plugin  http://kwebble.com/blog/2007_08_15/archives_for_a_category  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the readme.txt file of  [Archives for a category WordPress plugin](http://kwebble.com/blog/2007_08_15/archives_for_a_category).

The plugin author has stated following limitation on it.

## Limitations

This plugin does not work for weekly archives. The list with archive links is correct, but the 
links themselves do not include the category. So when used, WordPress will not filter the resulting 
page on the category.
The technical reason is that WordPress does not apply filters when the links for weekly archives 
are generated, so the plugin can't change them. Perhaps this is fixed in a next version of 
WordPress.

I checked latest version of wordpress(3.5.1) to find out whether this version has added any filter for weekly url but it has not added yet :(

I think you will have to develop custom code and sql query to implement this functionality and should not depend on Archives for a category WordPress plugin  and wp_get_archives function to implement this functionality.

Comment: thank Vinod Dalvi, when I got a custom SQL solution I'll post the answer here.